# HTML5 app with intel xdk app (android)

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, local-storage, indexeddb

i create  Html5 app using intel xdk (simple content with html pages ) with no database but now My teacher want me to add survey form and the scenario is when user click on submit form then data goes to database like in this web site (http://qec.org.pk/qec/index.php)(check in performa section) i'm making this website into mobile application .
i have no experience with server side language but know Mysql and i read about AJAX to retrive data from website but no success , i've read lot of stuff about databases but not working for me
please tell me how can i add database for survey form  easily  .
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given you know MySQL, I would say your simplest option is to use a MySQL database and create an api with PHP that you access with AJAX in your app. To get started with writing the PHP part, [w3school has a great and to the point introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp).

Accesing the API could look something like this with an AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({url: 'submit-survey.php?param1=' + param1 + '&param2' + param2 });
```

Hope this sends you off in the right direction.

Comment: is there any way that i can use main web site (http://qec.org.pk/) into my app for their own survey form and database ? , i've access to who made this website because  its urgent , i have to submit on friday so its hard to learn from skratch in limited time

Comment: yes that web site is fully functional with registration/login with all databases

Comment: i just have to make that web site into application (Andriod)